# JAVA SOAP Service Dependencies in TOMCAT

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, java-ws, java-ee-8

I have a `JAX-WS` service that also has some dependencies and I need to bundle them together as part of the `WAR file` so that when deployed to the server the dependencies are not installed in the normal `$TOMCAT/lib` directory which may affect other services running on the production server. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The war file is a zip archive that contains files and directories. It should contain a WEB-INF/lib directory where you store the dependencies (jar files in most of cases)

Comment: Is that where the `WebService` will first look when referencing depepndencies before the `$TOMCACT/lib` directory

Comment: Yes as explained in the [Tomcat classloader documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html).